# SharedPreferences object calling the listener if assigned value in java?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

If a SharedPreferences object is assigned a value, with java code somewhere in my mainActivity, will that alert the OnSharedPreferenceChangedListener?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Android documentation

"**OnSharedPreferenceChangedListner is called when a shared preference is changed, added, or removed. This may be called even if a preference is set to its existing value.**"

Here's the link for more info: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html